# How can i wait on severals threads completed their code?

Tags: java

I want to count Words with several Threads and every thread has a "wordCount" variable. Now how can i wait till every thread is finished? At the end i should count every variable of each thread together and print it out?

**How i create my Threads:**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= THREADS_TO_USE; i++) {
    long bytesToRead = splitManager();
    new Thread(new CountWordsThread(file, bytesToRead, bytesCounted)).start();
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into `ExecutorService` or even `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: A `CountDownLatch` can be used to wait until all the threads finish their work before allowing the main thread to continue it's work

Comment: Instead of creating new Threads, submit your Runnables to an ExecutorService, then call the ExecutorService’s `shutdown` method followed by a call to its `awaitTermination` method.